# How can I compile a Grails App including a Grails Plugin-Project on my Webserver?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have a Grails Project with name **AProject** and a Grails Plugin with name **MyPlugin**.

I integrate my **MyPlugin** into **AProject**, by adding to `BuildConfig.groovy` as:

```
plugins {
   ...
  compile ":elasticsearch:0.50" 
}

grails.plugin.location.'elasticsearch' = "../elasticsearch"
```

On my local computer I then do in the MyPlugin folder

```
grails maven-install
```

and in the AProject folder:

```
grails clean
grails refresh-dependencies
grails run-app
```

This is working fine on my local computer, but not on my server.

How can I integrate a Grails plugin project on my server?

Comment: Unless I misunderstood your question, on the webserver you will deploy your war file generated by `grails war` and that should include all the dependencies the application needs.

Comment: Rephrase the question heading, it is bit confusing. Do you want your plugin to be deployed as a grails app? It cannot be edited more fearing modifications would change the main objective of the question.

Comment: I want to compile my app on my webserver grails prod war and want to include a grails plugin project that way how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

- `grails maven-install //in plugin project if you have .m2 <local maven repo>`
- `compile ':my-plugin:0.1' //in Grails app BuildConfig plugin section`
- `grails war //in grails app`
- Deploy the `war` wherever you want.

If this is what you want then you would need nothing else.

Grails will package all compiled files into the war file. The Grails app would pull the plugin artifact from the maven repo (in this case your local maven repo) while building the war file.

If you are building the war on the same machine that you did `maven install` for the plugin your grails app will find it and you should be good.

Comment: I do not have a local maven repo how can I do it with a jar file?

Comment: @stephan1001 Plugins are always packaged as `zip`. Refer excerpts from [release plugin](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-release/docs/manual/guide/maven.html#mavenCache) about maven integration which is available to all newly created plugins by default.

Comment: I do not have a local maven repo. How should I do it in this case?

Comment: Download Maven. You just need to have `M2_HOME` set in classpath. I guess. Or I am not sure whether the release plugin create the repo for you when you run grails maven-install. Just run the above mentioned steps without installing Maven, otherwise follow as mentioned in this comment. @stephan1001

Comment: I am new with that sorry for the questions where is M2_HOME path set

Comment: @stephan1001 `M2_HOME` is set to the classpath with Maven home directory. Something like `M2_HOME=path/to/your/maven/home`.

Comment: and what is the default maven path?

Comment: when I do grails maven-install I alway get "Script 'MavenInstall' not found, did you mean:" what should I do?

Comment: Before doing maven install, compile (grails compile) your plugin project once you have installed the release plugin.

Comment: @stephan1001 Was the answer helpful?