# How to install grails plugin from github repo?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I looked in the Grails docs, but I could not find how to instruct the BuildConfig.groovy to tell my Grails app to get a plugin from a github repo. This is the repo I want to include, https://github.com/westonplatter/backbonejs-grails-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clone (or fork based on your need) the repo and build the plugin to create a `zip` and then use the plugin as a plugin dependency in `BuildConfig`.

Once cloned, you can use `grails maven-install` on the plugin so that the `zip` would be available in  local `.m2` repo if you have one. Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18219372/2051952) for steps and this for a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18453718/2051952).

Otherwise, you can directly use the plugin in your app by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16116125/2051952) or refer [Specifying Plugin Locations](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html).

Comment: I'm trying to install this https://github.com/danieldbower/grails-spring-security-cas-attribs which does have a released ZIP file, but I can't figure out how to reference the github repo. I tried with the obvious, but it doesn't work: `compile "com.github.danieldbower:grails-spring-security-cas-attribs:1.1.1"`